# How to use ternary operators and display the data in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In this code the `newArr` is having a data like [image]    and i want to display which `type=="sent"` should be display in right side and other data should be dipalyed on left side . But the issue is data is not diaplying .please help me thanks in advance

```
  { newArr ? newArr.map((m) => {
            (m.type === "sent") ? 
            <div style={{float:"right"}}>{m.msg}</div>
            : <div style={{float:"left"}}>{m.msg}</div>
          }): null }
```

Comment: yes , how to return this `<div style={{float:"right"}}>{m.msg}</div>` 
`

Comment: See the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You should return after the condition returned

```
 `{newArr ? newArr.map((m) => {
      return  (m.type === "sent") ? 
         <div style={{float:"right"}}>{m.msg}</div>
         :<div style={{float:"left"}}>{m.msg}</div>
       }): null }`
```